# JavaScript special characters/regular expressions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn from reading Mozilla documentation for regular expressions, but there's one thing I don't get. For the special character `\s` it gives the following example

/\s\w*/ matches ' bar' in "foo bar."

I understand that \s is the special character for white space, but why is there a w* in the example?

doesn't `/\s/` also match ' bar' in "foo bar."?

What's with the `w*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\s\w*/` is whitespace character followed by 0 or more word characters.

`/\s/` would only find the whitespace in the example.

Answer (score 1):

\w matches any alphanumerical character (word characters) including underscore (short for [a-zA-Z0-9_]).

It's a character escape.

Comment: thank you. so putting the /\w*\s/ would have returned "foo " in the example in the OP?

Answer (score 1):

`\w` is all word characters `(letters, digits, and underscores)`

Check this link for more [documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) on such shorthand